# Haskell Network "accept" unsupported operation (Function not implemented)

Tags: haskell, network-programming, debian

I've written a simple web server using `Network`, `System.IO` and `Data.Bytestring`. The components all communicate beautifully on several machines at home running Debian. However, when I attempt to run the program on the university servers (a less frequently updated Debian), I get the following error:

```
Waiting for connection on <socket: 3>
Broadcaster: accept: unsupported operation (Function not implemented)
```

The relevant lines of code are:

```
  sock <- listenOn port
  putStrLn $ "Waiting for connection on " ++ (show sock)
  (handle, host, hostPort) <- accept sock
```

I have compiled the application locally on the server it's running on (ghc 7.4.1 used consistently). I've tried with and without `withSocketsDo`.

Any ideas as to how I might fix this, please?

Comment: Are there version differences for the compiler used?

Comment: @arrowdodger Yes, I've tried withSocketsDo. Shouldn't be an issue on linux, anyway.

Comment: @mhitza No, using ghc 7.4.1 on all systems.

Comment: As far as I know, this usually happens when some operation is not implemented in the older kernel but on the newer kernel. So when ghc built on the newer kernel is used it will give not implemented error.

Comment: How you installed ghc on the server will be of greater help here.

Comment: @Mystic I don't have control over the server's setup, but I'll try building ghc myself and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was `ghc` built for `2.6.32-5-686-bigmem` being run on `2.6.23.17-general`.

```
<lab machine>% uname -r
2.6.32-5-686-bigmem
<server machine>% uname -r
2.6.23.17-general
```